# TYPO3 Media-Emelent own field

Tags: php, typo3, typo3-extensions, fal

is it possible to extend the media type in my typo3 extension?
Default fields are alternative, title, desription.
How can i add a own field?

```
$GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['types']['my_slider'] = [
        'showitem'         => '
                --palette--;' . $frontendLanguageFilePrefix . 'palette.general;general,
                --palette--;' . $languageFilePrefix . 'tt_content.palette.mediaAdjustments;mediaAdjustments,
                pi_flexform,
            --div--;' . $customLanguageFilePrefix . 'tca.tab.sliderElements,
                 assets
        ',
        'columnsOverrides' => [
            'media' => [
                'label'  => $languageFilePrefix . 'tt_content.media_references',
                'config' => \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::getFileFieldTCAConfig('media', [
                    'appearance'    => [
                        'createNewRelationLinkTitle' => $languageFilePrefix . 'tt_content.media_references.addFileReference'
                    ],
                    // custom configuration for displaying fields in the overlay/reference table
                    // behaves the same as the image field.
                    'foreign_types' => $GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['columns']['image']['config']['foreign_types']

                ], $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SYS']['mediafile_ext'])
            ]
        ]
    ];
```

Answer (score 0):

if you analyze the datastructure of your TYPO3 database you will find: those fields (`title` and `alternative`) are not fields in the table `sys_file` but in `sys_file_metadata` (and in `sys_file_reference` for overwriting them on a specific usage)

With that knowledge you can add your fields to these tables and give them a proper rendering and behaviour.

---

Adding the fields to `sys_file_metadata` will make them available for every file as default values if the fiel is used anywhere.
If you want these fields appear only at special usage you need to set the fields only for the table `sys_file_reference` which is used only for relations between a file and it's usage. AND you need to set conditions to show the fields only if your content elements use a file. This condition might be a litte complicated. if you use inidvidual tables the condition could be used the usage of this `foreign_table`, if you use `tt_content` records you also need to include the `CType`of the record in the condition. Probably you will need an `userfunc`.
Or you have an unique fieldname?

Comment: No, i dont have an unique fielname. Only the CType. I tought something like
If my CType then execute the Code from the sys_file_reference

Comment: then you could use a condition to make your fields in `sys_fiel_reference` visible in the record based on the fields `tablenames` and `fieldname`.